# Does jQuery .not() method require CSS Selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Along with a number of other `a` class elements, I've got a link with the markup

`<a class="editLink" href="www.somelink.com"> Edit <\a>`

And I want to select every `a` element using jQuery except those in this `editLink` class.

So I've used `a.not(".editLink")` for the jQuery selector which works fine. However I noticed that this also works when I do `a.not("editLink")` and `a.not("#editLink")`

It's like the jQuery ignores the CSS passed as part of the `not()` method argument. The docs suggest it is necessary to pass the id/class CSS but from what I can tell it's un-necessary.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Am I being stupid or is there some magic happening?

Thanks

---

Update - Okay I think I made an error with my syntax. I was doing:

```
$("p, a.not(".editLink")").click()...
```

When it should have been

```
$("p, a").not("a.editLink").click()...
```

So my bad. Interestingly though the original did select all the a element apart from those in the `editLink` class.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you share us the full javascript as what you've posted doesn't make sense in it's current form.

Comment: I'm using .not() - and I'll add some more script

Comment: @MAtt $("allElements").not("exceptions");
here's the difference: http://api.jquery.com/not/ and http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: `$("p, a").not("a.editLink")` Doesn't that select all `p` elements too? Unless that's what you want...

Comment: Yes it was - I think the multiple selectors threw me a bit. It was a silly mistake non the less but at least I know now. Thanks again everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does require a selector string. It's just treating `"editLink"` as a selector string that represents an element called `<editLink>`, which clearly your `<a>` elements are not.

So, your code `a.not("editLink")` "works"... just not the way you expect it to: instead of filtering out those elements that don't have a class with that name, it does nothing because none of the `<a>` elements are `<editLink>` elements. And, if none of your `<a>` elements have an ID with that name either, then the same goes for `a.not("#editLink")`.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use CSS for that like this: `$('a:not(.editLink)')`

Comment: That’s not actually answering the question.

Comment: I was just suggesting another (better) option for doing what you want because it uses native CSS selector. But if you wanna do it your way this is the way to do it: `$('a').not('.editLink')`